# Can two groups of N people find each other around a circle?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

This is an algorithmic problem and I'm not sure it has a solution. I think it's a specific case of a more generic computer science problem that has no solution but I'd rather not disclose which one to avoid planting biases. It came up from a real life situation in which mobile phones were out of credit and thus, we didn't have long range communications.

Two groups of people, each with 2 people (but it might be true for N people) arranged to meet at the center of a park but at the time of meeting, the park is closed. Now, they'll have to meet somewhere else around the park. Is there an algorithm each and every single individual could follow to converge all in one point?

For example, if each group splits in two and goes around and when they find another person keep on going with that person, they would all converge on the other side of the park. But if the other group does the same, then, they wouldn't be able to take the found members of the other group with them. This is not a possible solution.

I'm not sure if I explained well enough. I can try to draw a diagram.

Comment: you mean they can't take them with them because of conflicting instructions? (i.e. they all get the same instructions). It's an interesting problem :)

Comment: Do you consider a park as a 2d rectangular and people are walking on the perimeter?

Comment: What operations are allowed?

Comment: imo, just thoughts. 'swarming'? Are most people we see in this location likely be be part of 'our group'? If so then follow / join the largest group. The assumption to get to the correct place is 'follow the perimeter'?. However, as there is  a 'bunch of us' then we can just have a party anyway?

Comment: Perhaps it is worth specifying for clarity that they agree in advance on the algorithm.

Comment: I think you also need to specify that we are unable to distinguish points on the perimeter, to avoid the “Northernmost point” answer, which, though reasonable in practice, is not, I suspect, what you are interested in.

Comment: What information do they have? Can a person determine the group membership of other people they encounter?

Comment: This needs to be better-specified (before more answers come in). Voting to close.

Comment: How does having two (or n) groups change the problem from just one group of two persons, also known as a pair?

Comment: I am confused here...I think the direction of each person is important, but I think their walking speed is important as well...is everyone has same walking speed? or different? or I can assign any walking speed to them beforehand?

Comment: Superficially, your problem resembles the [rendezvous problem](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rrw1/abstracts/rendezvous.html) on the circle. However you're missing the important "suppose the locations are identical and unlabelled" condition which precludes the uninteresting "meet at the northernmost point" solution below.

Comment: Operation: everyone wait until the park opens :-)

Comment: Could you please clarify your specifications (as requested by various people), checking them against the assumptions in my proof of impossibilityin [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38043993/4847772)?.

Comment: I feel like this was closed for the wrong reason. It should be closed as off-topic since it is theoretical and belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com/. Even if it is narrowed down to a concise set of rules for the algorithm in question, it is still a better fit for that site than it is for stackoverflow.

Comment: The fact that it also fits on another site doesn't _ipso facto_ mean that it is should be unwelcome on this one, @PatrickRoberts.

Answer (score 18):

## Deterministic Solution for `N > 1, K > 1`

#### For `N` groups of `K` people each.

Since the problem is based on people whose mobile phones are out of credit, let's assume that each person in each group has their own phone. If that's not acceptable, then substitute the phone with a credit card, social security, driver's license, or any other item with numerical identification that is guaranteed to be unique.

In each group, each person must remember the highest number among that group, and the person with the highest number (labeled `leader`) must travel clockwise around the perimeter while the rest of the group stays put.

After the `leader` of each group meets the next group, they compare their number with the group's previous `leader` number.

If the leader's number is higher than the group's previous leader's number, then the leader and the group all continue along the perimeter of the park. If the group's previous leader's number is higher, then they all stay put.

Eventually the `leader` with the highest number will continue around the entire perimeter exactly 1 rotation, collecting the entire group.

### Deterministic solution for `N > 1, K = 1` (with one reasonable assumption of knowledge ahead-of-time)

In this case, each group only contains one person. Let's assume that the number used is a phone number, because it is then reasonable to also assume that at least one pair of people will know each other's numbers and so one of them will stay put.

For `N = 2`, this becomes trivially reduced to one person staying put and the other person going around clockwise.

For other cases, the fact that at least two people will initially know each other's numbers will effectively increase the maximum `K` to at least 2 (because the person or people who stay put will continue to stay put if the person they know has a higher number than the `leader` who shows up to meet them), but we still have to introduce one more step to the algorithm to make sure it will terminate.

The extra step is that if a `leader` has continued around the perimeter for exactly one rotation without adding anyone to the group, then the `leader` must leave their group behind and start over for one more rotation around the perimeter. This means that a `leader` with no group will continue indefinitely until they find someone else, which is good.

With this extra step, it is easy to see why we have to assume that at least one pair of people need to know each other's phone numbers ahead of time, because then we can guarantee that the person who stays put will eventually accumulate the entire group.

*Feel free to leave comments or suggestions to improve the algorithm I've laid out or challenge me if you think I missed an edge case. If not, then I hope you liked my answer.*

### Update

For fun, I decided to write a visual demo of my solutions to the problem using `d3`. Feel free to play around with the parameters and restart the simulation with any initial state. Here's the link:

https://jsfiddle.net/patrob10114/c3d478ty/show/

**Key**

- **black** - leader
- **white** - follower
- *when clicked*

  - **blue** - selected person
  - **green** - known by selected person
  - **red** - unknown by selected person

Note that `collaboration` occurs at the start of every `step`, so if two groups just combined in the current step, most people won't know the people from the opposite group until after the next `step` is invoked.

Comment: That's brilliant, especially with the D3 animation.

Answer (score 14):

They should move towards the northernmost point of the park.

Comment: that's like saying "they should meet at Mcdonalds", but sure

Comment: Yeah, but a) McDonalds is not part of the problem while the park is, and b) meeting at the northernmost point of the park sure sounds healthier.

Comment: or you can say move towards each other. Each group is a part of the problem, so 'it will surely work'.

Comment: What if the park is at the north pole? Or the south pole? Or in a space station orbiting earth? Or (any other frame of reference where this rule can't be applied)?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Based on the wording of the problem, I assumed that the algorithm is known by all groups and they also know that all other groups know the algorithm.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I certainly like the idea of a park at the north pole. The problem does not clearly state whether the geometry of the situation may be taken into account and if so, which assumptions may be made about it.

Comment: That is to say, in the absence of prior agreement they should make their best guess at a Schelling point. This approach either works well because the groups both choose the same place to meet (they both choose the north), or fails catastrophically because they choose different points (one chooses the north, the other chooses the south) and never meet en route.

Comment: Well, they would have to know where the northernmost point of the park is. And if they have a compass, why not a phone?

Comment: @palsch 1. Wait for unclouded night. 2. walk in the direction which leads towards Polaris. But yeah, I obviously make some assumptions which are not necessarily true.

Comment: @flyx If they can wait for the night, why can't they wait until the park opens?

Comment: @palsch good point.

Answer (score 9):

I'd send both groups in a random direction. If they went a half circle without meeting the other group, rerandomize the directions. This will make them meet in a few rounds most of the time, however there is an infinitely small chance that they still never meet.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question (which probably should be on the theoretical computer science site, so a pragmatic answer isn't terrible :p)

Comment: As long as we have infinite time, eventually the groups will meet. Nice answer.

Comment: How will they know that they passed half a circle?

Comment: That depends. I assumed they know the geometry of the park and can measure how much they went. If they dont know the size of the park they could just double the amount of walking time everytime they randomize directions, starting with 1 sec. If they can't measure time nor distances, then we really cant do better than random roaming.

Comment: @keyser Right, this procedure isn't an algorithm as it is not guaranteed to eventually end. This can take arbitrary many steps.

Answer (score 7):

It is **not possible** with a **deterministic** algorithm if

- • we have to meet at some point on the perimeter,
- • we are unable to distinguish points on the perimeter (or the algorithm is not allowed to use such a distinction),
- • we are unable to distinguish individuals in the groups (or the algorithm is not allowed to use such a distinction),
- • the perimeter is circular (*see below for a more general case*),
- • we all follow the same algorithm, and
- • the initial points may be anywhere on the perimeter.

**Proof**: With a deterministic algorithm we can deduce the final positions from the initial positions, but the groups could start evenly spaced around the perimeter, in which case the problem has rotational symmetry and so the solution will be unchanged by a 1/n rotation, which however has no fixed point on the perimeter.

**Status of assumptions**
Dropping various assumptions leads, as others have observed to various solutions:

- **Non-deterministic**: As others have observed, various non-deterministic algorithms do provide a solution whose probability of termination tends to certainty as time tends to infinity; I suspect almost any random walk would do. (*Many answers*)
- **Points indistinguishable**: Agree on a fixed point at which to meet if needed: *[flyx’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38042949/4847772)*.
- **Individuals indistinguishable**: If there is a perfect hash algorithm, choose those with the lowest hash to collect others: *[Patrick Roberts’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38046300/4847772)*.
- **Same algorithm**: Choose one in advance to collect the others (adapting *Patrick Roberts’s solution*).

Other assumptions can be weakened:

- **Non-circular perimeter**: The condition that the perimeter be circular is rather artificial, but if the perimeter is topologically equivalent to a circle, this equivalence can be used to convert any solution to a solution to the circle problem.
- **Unrestricted initial points**: Even if the initial points cannot be evenly spaced, as long as some points are distinct, a topological equivalence (as for a non-circular perimeter) reduces a solution to a solution to the circular case, showing that no solution can exist.

I think this question really belongs on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Adding to your list of assumptions that prevent a deterministic solution, one should also add the assumption that we cannot distinguish the „persons“ from each other, i.e. there is no perfect hash function for the persons. Otherwise, it would be trivial to spread the knowledge of said hash of each person (let's say, their social security number) and then have the person with the lowest number start walking and taking all the others with them as they meet, until everybody is in this group.

Comment: @flyx: Good point. Of course, if we assume that the groups are incommunicado, they would have to determine the lowest hash in advance, after which their ‘effective algorithms’ would be different, but that is not forbidden.

Comment: @flyx: Edited. (Also improved presentation)

Answer (score 6):

This question heavily depends on what kind of operations do we have and what do you consider your environment looks like. I asked your this questions with no reply, so here is my interpretation:

The park is a 2d space, 2 groups are located randomly, each group has the same right/left (both are facing the park). Both have the same operations are programmed to do absolutely the same things (nothing like I go right, and you go left, because this makes the problem obvious). So the operations are: Go right/left/stop for x units of time. They can also figure out that they passed through their original position (the one in which they started). And they can be programmed in a loop.

[image]

If you have an ability to use randomness - everything is simple. You can come up with many solutions. For example: with probability 0.5 each of them decide to that they will either do 3 steps right and wait. Or one step right and wait. If you will do this operation in a loop and they will select different options, then clearly they will meet (one is faster than the other, so he will reach a slower person). If they both select the same operation, than they will make a circle and both reach their starting positions. In this case roll the dice one more time. After N circles the probability that they will meet will be 1 - 0.5^n (which approaches 1 very fast)

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, there is a way to do it!  But first we have to define our terms and assumptions.

We have N=2 "teams" of K=2 "agents" apiece. Each "agent" is running the same program. They can't tell north from south, but they can tell clockwise from counterclockwise. Agents in the same place can talk to each other; agents in different places can't.

Your suggested partial answer was: "If each group splits in two and goes around and when they find another person keep on going with that person, they would all converge on the other side of the park..."  This implies that our agents have some (magic, axiomatic) face-to-face decision protocol, such that if Alice and Bob are on the same team and wake up at the same point on the circle, they can (magically, axiomatically) decide amongst themselves that Alice will head clockwise and Bob will head counterclockwise (as opposed to Alice and Bob always heading in exactly the same direction because by definition they react exactly the same way to the situation they're identically in).

One way to implement this magic decision protocol is to give each agent a **personal random number generator**. Whenever 2 or more agents are gathered at a certain point, they all roll a million-sided die, and whichever one rolls highest is acknowledged as the leader. So in your partial solution, Alice and Bob could each roll: whoever rolls higher (the "leader") goes clockwise and sends the other agent (the "follower") counterclockwise.

Okay, having solved the "how do our agents make decisions" issue, let's solve the actual puzzle!

Suppose our teams are (Alice and Bob) and (Carl and Dave). Alice and Carl are the initially elected leaders.

- Step 1: Each team rolls a million-sided die to generate a random number. The semantics of this number are "The team with the higher number is the Master Team," but of course neither team knows right now who's got the higher number. But Alice and Bob both know that their number is let's say 424202, and Carl and Dave both know that *their* number is 373287.
- Step 2: Each team sends its leader around the circle clockwise, while the follower stays stationary. Each leader stops moving when he gets to where the other team's follower is waiting. So now at one point on the circle we have Alice and Dave, and at the other point we have Carl and Bob.
- Step 3: Alice and Dave compare numbers and realize that Alice's team is the Master Team. Likewise, Bob and Carl compare numbers and realize that Bob's team is the Master Team.
- Step 4: Alice being the leader of the Master Team, she takes Dave with her clockwise around the circle. Bob and Carl (being a follower and a leader of a non-master team respectively) just stay put. When Alice and Dave reach Bob and Carl, the problem is solved!

---

Notice that Step 1 requires that both teams roll a million-sided die *in isolation*; if during Step 3 everyone realizes that there was a tie, they'll just have to backtrack and try again. Therefore this solution is still probabilistic... but you can make its expected time arbitrarily small by just replacing everyone's million-sided dice with trillion-sided, quintillion-sided, bazillion-sided... dice.

---

The general strategy here is to impose a pecking order on all N×K agents, and then bounce them around the circle until everyone is aware of the pecking order; then the top pecker can just sweep around the circle and pick everyone up.

Imposing a pecking order can be done by using the agents' personal random number generators.

The protocol for K>2 agents per team is identical to the K=2 case: you just glom all the followers together in Step 1. Alice (the leader) goes clockwise while Bob[neric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_the_Flies) (the followers) stay still; and so on.

The protocol for K=1 agents per team is... well, it's impossible, because no matter what you do, you can't *deterministically* ensure that anyone will ever encounter another agent. You need a way for the agents to ensure, *without communicating at all*, that they won't all just circle clockwise around the park forever.

---

One thing that would help with (but not technically solve) the K=1 case would be to consider the relative *speeds* of the agents. You might be familiar with Floyd's "Tortoise and Hare" algorithm for [finding a loop in a linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare). Well, if the agents are allowed to move at non-identical speeds, then you could certainly do a "continuous, multi-hare" version of that algorithm:

- Step 1: Each agent rolls a million-sided die to generate a random number *S*, and starts running clockwise around the park at speed *S*.
- Step 2: Whenever one agent catches up to another, both agents glom together and start running clockwise at a new random speed.
- Step 3: Eventually, ***assuming that nobody picked exactly the same random speeds***, everyone will have met up.

This protocol requires that Alice and Carl not roll identical numbers on their million-sided dice *even when they are across the park from each other*. IMHO, this is a very different assumption from the other protocol's assuming that Alice and Bob could roll different numbers on their million-sided dice *when they were in the same place*. With K=1, we're never guaranteed that two agents will *ever* be in the same place.

---

Anyway, I hope this helps. The solution for N>2 teams is left as an exercise for the reader, but my intuition is that it'll be easy to reduce the N>2 case to the N=2 case.

Comment: Tortoise and hare sprang to mind for me immediately as well. I like the random speed change after meeting.

Comment: Well, the random speed change after meeting doesn't matter at all, AFAIK, since one random speed won't be any *more* random than another. It was just shorter to write "at a new random speed" than to make up some other arbitrary rule such as "at the max of their two speeds" or "at one of their two speeds chosen at random" or whatever.

Comment: It matters, because (for group size 2) if the groups start at opposite points on the perimeter, they will still be at opposite points when each hare meets a tortoise, and if both clumps pick the same of the two original speeds, the two clumps will never meet.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: But the "two original speeds" are both chosen uniformly at random by rolling million-sided dice! They're vanishingly unlikely to be *the same*; and if we care about the chance that they *are* the same, then we should also care about the chance that the *new* randomly chosen speeds will happen to be exactly the same.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying, sorry. You're right. I think I read your solution too quickly and conflated it with the problematic one that I had in my head. So let me amend my original comment to "I like the random speeds". :)

Answer (score 3):

Each group sends out a scout with the remaining group members remaining stationary.  Each group remembers the name of their scout.  The scouts circle around clockwise, and whenever he meets a group, they compare names of their scouts:

1. If scout's name is earlier alphabetically: group follows him.
2. If scout's name is later: he joins the group and gives up his initial group identity.

By the time the lowest named scout makes it back the his starting location, everyone who hasn't stopped at his initial location should be following him.

Answer (score 2):

There are some solutions here that to me are unsatisfactory since they require the two teams to agree a strategy in advance and all follow the same deterministic or probabilistic rules. If you had the opportunity to agree in advance what rules you're all going to follow, then as flyx points out you could just have agreed a backup meeting point. Restrictions that prevent the advance choice of a particular place or a particular leader are standard in the context of some problems with computer networks but distinctly un-natural for four friends planning to meet up. Therefore I will frame a strategy from the POV of only one team, assuming that there has been no prior discussion of the scenario between the two teams.

Note that it is not possible to be robust in the face of *any* strategy from the other team. The other team can always force a stalemate simply by adopting some pattern of movement that ensures *those two* will never meet again.

- One of you sets out walking around the park. The other stands still, let us say at position X. This ensures that: (a) you will meet each other periodically at X, let us say every T seconds; and (b) for each member of the other team, no matter how they move around the perimeter of the park they must encounter at least one of your team at least every T seconds.
- Now you have communication among all members of both groups, and (given sufficient time and passing-on of messages from one person to another) the problem resolves to the same problem as if your mobile phones were working. Choosing a leader by random number is one way to solve it as others have suggested. Note that there are still two issues: the first is a two-generals problem with communication, and I suppose you might feel that a mobile phone conversation allows for the generation of common knowledge whereas these relayed notes do not. The second is the possibility that the other team refuses to co-operate and you cannot agree a meeting point no matter what.
- Notwithstanding the above problems, the question supposes that if they had communication that the groups would be able to agree a meeting-point. You have communication: agree a meeting point!
- As for how to agree a meeting point, I think it requires some appeal to reason or good intention on the part of the other team. If they are due to meet again, then they will be very reluctant to take any action that results in them breaking their commitment to their partner. Therefore suggest to them both that *after their next meeting*, when all commitments can be forgiven, they proceed together to X by the shortest route. Listen to their counter-proposal and try to find some common solution.

To help reach a solution, you could pre-agree with your team-mate some variations you'd be willing to make to your plan, provided that they remain within some restrictions that ensure you will meet your team-mate again. For example, if the stationary team-mate agrees that they could be persuaded to set out clockwise, and the moving team-mate sets out anti-clockwise and agrees that they can be persuaded to do something different but not to cross point X in a clockwise direction, then you're guaranteed to meet again and so you can accept certain suggestions from the other team.

Just as an example, if a team following this strategy meets a team (unwisely) following your strategy, then one of my team will agree to go along with the one of your team they meet, and the other will refuse (since it would require them to make the forbidden movement above). This means that when your team meet together, they'll have one of my team with them for a group of three. The loose member of my team is on a collision course with that group of three provided your team doesn't do anything perverse.

I think forming any group of three is a win, so each member should do anything they can to attend a meeting of the other team, subject to the constraints they agreed to guarantee they'll meet up with their own team member again. A group of 3, once formed, should follow whatever agreement is in place to meet the loose member (and if the team of two contained within that 3 refuses to do this then they're saboteurs, there is no good reason for them to refuse). Within these restrictions, any kind of symmetry-breaking will allow the team following these principles to persuade/follow the other team into a 3-way and then a 4-way meeting.

In general some symmetry-breaking is required, if only because both teams might be following my strategy and therefore both have a stationary member at different points.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the park is a circle. (for the sake of clarity)

**Group A**

- Person A.1
- Person A.2

**Group B**

- Person B.1
- Person B.2

**We (group A)** are currently at the bottom of the circle (90 degrees). We **agree to go towards 0 degrees in opposite directions**. I'm person A.1 and I go clockwise. I send Person A.2. counterclockwise.

**In any possible scenario (B splits, B doesn't split, B has the same scheme, B has some elaborate scheme), each group might have conflicting information. So unless Group A has a gun to force Group B into submission, the new groups might make conflicting choices upon meeting.**

Say for instance, A.1. meets B.1, and A.2. meets B.2. What do we (A.1 and B.1) do if B has the same scheme? Since the new groups can't know what the other group decides (whether to go with A's scheme, or B's scheme), each group might make different decision.

**And we'll end up where we started... (i.e. two people at 0 degrees, and two people at 90 degrees).** Let's call this checkpoint "First Iteration".

We might account for this and say that we'll come up with a scheme for the "Second Iteration". But then the same thing happens again. And for the third iteration, fourth iteration, ad infinitum.

Each iteration has a 50% chance of not working out.

**Which means that after x iterations, your chances of not meeting up at a common point are at most 1-(0.5^x)**

N.B. I thought about a bunch of scenarios, such as Group A agreeing to come back to their initial point, and communicating with each other what Group B plans to do. But no cigar, turns out even with very clever schemes the conflicting information issue always arises.

Comment: It seems you are assuming group B may take a different approach, but I have the impression from _“Is there an algorithm each and every single individual could follow”_ that we are looking for an algorithm which all groups are to agree in advance to follow (should the need arise).

Comment: "Each iteration has a 50% chance of not working out." I need to see evidence of this point before I believe it.

Comment: You mention thinking about other scenarios — [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38043993/4847772) shows that no deterministic solution exists, given some reasonable interpretations of the question.

Comment: "which all groups are to agree in advance to follow (should the need arise)"... 

This means the groups can communicate, so to speak. If everyone could agree to the same algorithm, then everyone can agree to go to the same point.

Comment: "I need to see evidence of this point before I believe it." It's an upper bound for the worst case scenario (i.e. both groups have the same scheme, and each group makes a decision that conflicts with the other). 

----

"some reasonable interpretations of the question." I think this is key. I interpreted using OPs " It came up from a real life situation in which mobile phones "

Answer (score 1):

An interesting problem indeed. I'd like to suggest my version of the solution:

0 Every group picks a leader.
1: Leader and followers go opposite directions

2: They meet other group leaders or followers

3: They keep going the same direction as before, 90 degrees magnitude

4: By this time, all groups have made a half-circle around the perimeter, and invariably have met leaders again, theirs, or others'.

5: All Leaders change the next step direction to that of the followers around,and order them to follow.

6: Units from all groups meet at one point.

Refer to the attached file for an in-depth explanation. You will need MS Office Powerpoint 2007 or newer to view it. In case you don't have one, use pptx. viewer (Powerpoint viewer) as a free alternative.

[Animated Solution (.pptx)](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05916978145167121912)

EDIT: I made a typo in the first slide. It reads "Yellow and red are selected", while it must be "Blue and red" instead.

Comment: The presentation deals with 90-degrees angles for clarity purposes. The method, however, is applicable to any starting or moving angles of the groups. Please let me know if it doesn't work for some cases, or similar solution has been already suggested.

Comment: It is better to put the summary of the attached file to your answer.

Comment: Summary added as per advice.

Comment: The question implies that all agents must follow the same rules; no "leader" may be distinguished.

Comment: The algorithm is the same for everyone. Just in terms of logic, all members check the condition "Am I Leader==1" before doing everything else. If true, they do the "Leader" procedure, otherwise, "follower". I take it units are allowed to store values in their local memory, be it RL people, robots, videogame characters, etc.

Comment: How does only one agent set `isLeader` in the first place if everyone is following the same rule?

Comment: Very simple. People from the group talk to each other and pick one. Easy! Ok, that's a fun answer, now, the serious one: 

It is taken as granted, that units cannot all stand at EXACTLY one point (i.e. cannot clip into each other like ghosts). That means, they will stand in some sort of formation. It is not hard to make them all stand in a North-South line (as shown in my presentation) with a pathfinding/sorting algorithm everyone would run. Cont-d:

Comment: Then, every unit in a group does the following procedure (pseudocode):
0: If (there is an another group member north of me==1) then            {imLeader=0} else {imLeader=1}. This will elect the most northern member a leader even without having to synchronize the machines (communicate between units). That is the case given most primitive decision-making of group members. I consider, that in 95% of practical applications of the situation (2 groups around an obstacle must meet), this will not be the case.

Comment: Or, if we are talking about purely mathematical situation (2 sets of values, must be grouped around another, bigger data set) then sorting algorithms will do the job, since in that case, group members (essentially just numbers) are incapable of any motion on their own and must be moved by 3rd party (e.g. person or a computing device).

Comment: Downvoted because of attached file. (Also have a look at [this post on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266714/1025391).)

Answer (score 0):

Each group will split in two parts, and each part will go around the circle in the opposite direction (clockwise and counterclockwise).

Before they start, they choose some kind of random number (in a range large enough so that there is no possibility for two groups to have the same number... or a Guid in computer science : globally unique identifier). So one unique number per group.

If people of the same group meet first (the two parts meet), they are alone, so probably the other groups (if any) gave up.

If two groups meet : they follow the rule that say the biggest number leads the way. So when they meet they continue in the direction that had people with the biggest number.

At the end, the direction of the biggest number will lead them all to one point.

If they have no computer to choose this number, each group could use the full names of the people of the group merged together.

**Edit** : sorry I just see that this is very close to Patrick Roberts' solution

**Another edit** : what if each group has its own deterministic strategy ?
In the solution above, all works well if all the groups have the same strategy. But in a real life problem this is not the case (as they cant communicate).

If one group has a deterministic strategy and the others have none, they can agree to follow the deterministic approach and all is ok.

But if two groups have deterministic approaches (simply for instance, the same as above, but one group uses the biggest number and the other group follows the lowest number).

Is there a solution to that ?